# search value in listview itemsource by index number wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm using Wpf MVVM, if i know the index number of item/row then how can i search the value in listview/itemsource by specific index number.

Note: i can get index number, index number will already be known.

below is the xaml code for listview

```
<ListView                       
    Grid.Row="1"
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource FileItemStyle}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding BarCode, IsAsync=True}"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectBarCode, 
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    Style="{StaticResource ListItemsMain}"
```

and ObservableCollection for itemsource

```
 private ObservableCollection<BarCodeModel> mBarCode = null;
 public ObservableCollection<BarCodeModel> BarCode
    {
        get
        {
            mBarCode = mBarCode ?? new ObservableCollection<BarCodeModel>();
            return mBarCode;
        }
    }
```

and below code is for model

```
public class BarCodeModel
{
    public int BarCodeEntry_ID { get; set; }
    public string BarCodeEntry_Title { get; set; }
```

and below is the command where i want to put my logic

```
private ICommand mSearchValueByIndexNumberCommand;
public ICommand SearchValueByIndexNumberCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (mSearchValueByIndexNumberCommand == null)
            {
                mSearchValueByIndexNumberCommand = new DelegateCommand(delegate ()
                {
                    // search BarCodeEntry_ID in BarCode where SelectedIndex is 5 (or other value)

                });
            }
            return mSearchValueByIndexNumberCommand;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's already in `SelectBarCode`

Comment: @vasily.sib thanks for replying, but i don't want to involve SelectBarCode

Comment: SearchValueByIndexNumberCommand button is outside from listview

Comment: Then you may try `BarCode[SelectedIndex]`. But it's the same thing.

Comment: @vasily.sib i think you are correct, could you post it as answer but in detail

Comment: @vasily.sib: post it as answer and score some points ;-) ... meanwhile... `ElementAt<T>(Int32)` is also available. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: ok thanks man, let me post it

Comment: As a note, you would usually not bind SelectedIndex and SelectedItem at the same time. Bind either the one or the other.

Comment: Thanks @Clemens, i will follow your instruction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in your XAML you bind your `ListView.ItemsSource` to `BarCode` of your ViewModel, but also bind `ListView.SelectedItem` and `ListView.SelectedIndex` to `SelectBarCode` and `SelectedIndex`, now, when you select some Item in a ListView, it (ListView) will update values of `SelectBarCode` and `SelectedIndex` in your ViewModel.

So, you can access your current selection with `SelectBarCode` or `BarCode[SelectedIndex]`.

Answer (score 0):

Below is answer to my question, a special thanks to @vasily.sib

```
private ICommand mSearchValueByIndexNumberCommand;
public ICommand SearchValueByIndexNumberCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (mSearchValueByIndexNumberCommand == null)
        {
            mSearchValueByIndexNumberCommand = new DelegateCommand(delegate ()
            {
               int BarCodeId = BarCode[SelectedIndex].BarCodeEntry_ID;

            });
        }
        return mSearchValueByIndexNumberCommand;
    }
}
```